# What is the single word for "agricultural good of low value"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'd like to know what is the single (simple) word in English for "agricultural good of low value", if there is any.

Comment: There isn't a word.

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568619) on multiple sites. Choose the most appropriate one, and unless it gets closed as off-topic, you should keep it only on that site.

Comment: I have deleted this from another site.

Answer (score 1):

"good agricultural land of low value" is in itself surely an oxymoron. If the land is good it must be of high value.

I suggest that what you mean is **"good agricultural land with a low valuation"**

As far as I am aware there is no word for this situation. Especially when "Agricultural land in itself covers such abroad spectrum.

---

**Agricultural land is defined as** the land area that is either arable, under permanent crops, or under permanent pastures. Arable land includes land under temporary crops such as cereals, temporary meadows for mowing or for pasture, land under market or kitchen gardens, and land temporarily fallow. Land abandoned as a result of shifting cultivation is excluded. Land under permanent crops is cultivated with crops that occupy the land for long periods and need not be replanted after each harvest, such as orchards and vineyards. This category excludes land under trees grown for wood or timber. Permanent pasture is land used for five or more years for forage, including natural and cultivated crops.

---

**valuation;** noun [ C ]; the act of saying how much something is worth: Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/valuation)

Comment: I modified the original post. I ask this question because in French the word is *benace*.

Comment: I think the word _good_ in the original is being used in the sense that economists use it so it does not imply good agricultural land.